# Magento 2.4.2 - Addtocart Button Disabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

Is anyone using `Magento 2.4.2 version`?.

In list page,`list.phtml` file  `Add to Cart` button is disabled.

How we can enable the `Add to Cart` button. Kindly confirm.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see this problem on a default Magento 2.4.2 installation. Can you provide more information, Have you upgraded to 2.4.2 or is it a new installation? Are you using a custom theme? Have you checked your log files for errors?

Comment: I have upgraded 2.3.4 to 2.4.2 . Yes am using custom theme. If am opening the venodr/magento/module-catalog/product/list.phtml file .there <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary" disabled>
                                                <span>Add to Cart</span>
                                            </button>

Comment: @priya in your custom theme you overwrite catalog-add-to-cart.js?
if yes then compare default js file.
Magento 2.4.2 added "$(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).attr('disabled', false);" in _create function.

Comment: Can confirm we have the same issue regardless of theme selected on our Magento ver. 2.4.2 store

Comment: Check if the products are not OUT OF STOCK

Comment: @Priya Please try to disable your third party theme and extensions and see if you are still  getting this issue or not.

Comment: Did anyone experience 404 not found after installing Magento 2.4.2 on local server?

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2.4.2 "Add to Cart" button is disabled in template and is being enabled using js post initialization

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

in **_create** function

```
_create: function () {
    if (this.options.bindSubmit) {
        this._bindSubmit();
    }
    $(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).attr('disabled', false);
}
```

You need to debug if it is overridden in **custom theme** or in any **third party plugin** you are using, because it works as expected on fresh Magento 2.4.2 installation. This change is added in Magento 2.4.2, it wasn't there in Magento 2.4.1.

Comment: Weird thing is the same behaviour is observed on the product page, but the button successfully enables on those pages

Comment: Yes, because different js is responsible to enable button on product page which is located at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/validate-product.js` **_create** function.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file path

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Click `ctrl+F` and search for `action tocart primary`

```
<button type="submit" title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"class="action tocart primary">
<span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>
</span></button>
```

Just replace button tag with this code and run (As you mentioned in comments disabled is there just remove or replace the button tag with above code)

For ubuntu

```
sudo rm -rf generated/* var/* && sudo bin/magento cache:flush
```

For windows

```
rm -rf generated/* var/* && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was an issue with invalid form key errors when add to cart was clicked before the page was fully loaded.

The change ensures that the add to cart button is enabled only when the page is fully loaded and `catalog-add-to-cart.js` has been processed.

The commit from August 2020 can be seen here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/95859dc036a6076423f30409f224a6b5d6f5ac84

This change will cause problems if you are extending `catalog-add-to-cart.js` in your custom theme or modules. You should update your custom/extended js to activate the add to cart button.

```
$(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).attr('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded from 2.4.1 to 2.4.2, got the same problem. The "add to cart" is grey in the product listing page. I have a very simple theme installed, no 3rd party addons. Even if changed back to original Luma theme, still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was introduce in Magento 2.4.2.

To make it work, you can change the `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` to `No`
[image: After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart]

More info:

- [Issue #32232 - Add to Cart broken on lists view with redirect to cart enabled · magento/magento2 · GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32232)
- [Add to Cart broken on lists view with redirect to cart enabled. by engcom-Kilo · Pull Request #32301 · magento/magento2 · GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/32301)

If you need to keep `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` to `Yes`, you can apply this patch:

- [32301.patch · magento/magento2 · GitHub](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/32301.patch)